# Recover deleted redo log files

Tags: oracle, linux, recovery, log, oracle-19c

I have the following problem: all redo log files from an Oracle 19C database have been deleted while the database was running. The database is running on a Linux server. When I try to connecting to the database, an error ORA-12514 ("TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor") is displayed. How can I restore the database?

Comment: I found a new bug with this. One user does not work, neither the delete nor the database queries do not workcin the schema. Ibgot the following errors:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to recover from an RMAN backup. The recovery process will recreate the online redo logs. See here for example: https://oracledbwr.com/oracle-19c-recover-a-loss-of-all-online-redo-log-files-using-rman/

> ```
> $ sqlplus / as sysdba
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jun 19 11:56:52 2019
> Version 19.3.0.0.0
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to:
> Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
> Version 19.3.0.0.0
>
> SQL> shut immediate 
> Database closed.
> Database dismounted.
> ORACLE instance shut down.
>
> $ sqlplus / as sysdba
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jun 20 00:41:38 2019
> Version 19.3.0.0.0
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
> Connected to an idle instance.
> SQL> startup mount;
> ORACLE instance started.
> Total System Global Area 2415917880 bytes
> Fixed Size            8899384 bytes
> Variable Size       520093696 bytes
> Database Buffers   1879048192 bytes
> Redo Buffers          7876608 bytes
> Database mounted.
> SQL>
>
> ... Connect to RMAN and recover until the available sequence...
>
> RMAN> run
> 2> {
> 3> restore database;
> 4> recover database;
> 5> alter database open resetlogs;
> 6> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. The files are displayed, but the error message (ORA-12514) appears the same way when connecting to the database.

Comment: That's a networking error; looks like the database is down. Did you open it at the end of the restore as shown in the script, or shutdown and re-open it normally after the restore?

Comment: I got this error after the restore. I started to investigate further. And I found an error like this: ORA-00600: [4194]. And then I solved it by modifying the Undo related parameter. Based on this: https://aprakash.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/ora-00600-4194-a-b/?fbclid=IwAR03C27Jwewz2CODCe6VrOmgKyFkr46LrMXAk9S6NWGJHcJY084duYaqP-w Thanks for your help.